CiviCRM Joomla Demo Site Not Working
I'm trying to find a Joomla online demo of CiviCRM without any luck! The demo link on the Joomla Extensions listing goes nowhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/

It is also reported as being off-line at https://civicrm.org/demo?field_language_value=All&field_cms_demo_value=joomla

You could search "in:joomla demo" at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/joomla or ask advice there. not that many joomla users afaik
